# Java GUI How to Popup Message Windows like MSN Messenger

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

My Java application sometimes stays at system tray, just like MSN messenger does. I need popup a window to display some formated texts. Sometimes there is more than 1 message entry. I need to display them all.

I am new to jave Swing/GUI.

Anyone has idea or experience on this?

Comment: Screenshots of what you're looking for will help a lot - I, at least, haven't used MSN Messenger in 10 years or so :)

Comment: A small borderless window appearing at the bottom-right corner of the screen. Can appear with an effect. It get dismissed in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had the opportunity to work with the Java system tray functionality yet, but you might be interested in reading this [overview](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/).

One particular section that appears to describe what you want is this:

> Finally, if you wish to casually notify the user of a change in application status using a tooltip from the tray icon, use the `displayMessage()`  method. This method displays a popup message near the tray icon, which will disappear after a time or if the user clicks on it. Clicking on the message may trigger an `ActionEvent`, depending on the platform.

That sounds like it describes what you want to do, but I'm not sure if there are any limitations on it. With that, the [`SystemTray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) and [`TrayIcon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) classes might be of interest as well, although I'm guessing that you've read them already.

Answer (score 1):

The system tray functionality in Java 6 allows you to do what you want.  Namely have an icon there, which your application can then react to.  The functionality to show a message bubble is available.

I have found that the display of multiple individual messages varies a lot between platforms, so I would group them together in a time interval and show them together instead of individual bubbles.

Have a look at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

Comment: `SystemTray` only looks OK in windows... In Linux, it looks like a GTK app from 90's. Sad...